# Stripe Payment in Javascript createToken callback not calling

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

In the following code, I have a problem where Stripe is not processing the payment. I'm getting all the values from the form correctly, however in the stripeResponseHandler function nothing is logging. I'm using the test credit cards available on their website and I successfully used it a couple of times prior to this error.

I loaded the https://js.stripe.com/v2/stripe-debug.js into my javascript and it was logging in the chrome console that "It looks like Stripe.js was loaded more than one time. Please only load it once per page.", however I only setPublishableKey here within this JS file and load

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_TK18ZwUnK2CT1Wmof8WsQl8S');

var payMeal = function(){
    console.log("inside the paymeals function");

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("form-payment");

    console.log("Number is " + x[0].value)
    console.log("CVC is " + x[1].value)
    console.log("Exp_Month is " + x[2].value)
    console.log("Exp_Year is " + x[3].value)
    console.log("The Stripe Object is",Stripe)

    Stripe.card.createToken({
    number: x[0].value,
    cvc: x[1].value,
    exp_month: x[2].value,
    exp_year: x[3].value
    }, stripeResponseHandler)


    window.location.href = "../../meals"
};

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response){
    console.log("IM IN THE RESPONSE HANDLER!!!!+++++***")
    if(response.error){
        console.log("THERE IS AN ERROR!!***")
        console.log(response);
    }
    else{
        console.log("submitting ajax to server with token");
        token = response.id;
        ajaxToServer(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you loading the `stripe.js` now?

Comment: what is the error you say you are getting? Look in the network tab, and see if you are getting an error rersponse.

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce the problem, and share the link here?

Comment: Hey @hanson, were you able to resolve this?